# Send SMS with SmsManager

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am trying to make an android app in Android Studio that will send an sms message containing a fixed message to a fixed number on the press of a button.

I have created a layout with a button named button1.

This is my MainActivity.java (taken off stackoverflow, it looked simple and good)

```
package com.example.hfbkalarm;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
sendMySmsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 sendMySmsBtn.setonclickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void Onclick()
    {
        sendSMS("<the number goes here>", "<message goes here>");
    });


private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message,null, null);
}
```

the sendMySmsBtn shows up red and says Cannot resolve symbol 'sendMySmsBtn' and i get 10 errors when trying to run it on my phone.

I have very little experience with this and im completely lost since every answer on the same question seems different.

EDIT

I did the things Nisalon suggested in his edited answer.

In thisa part "(new OnClickListener()" the OnClickListener is still red, but now it gives me an option to import OnClickListener in View or DialogInterface

Also the OnClick after that part is grey and says the variable is never used.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button sendMySmsBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    sendMySmsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sendMySmsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void Onclick()
        {
            sendSMS("<the number goes here>", "<message goes here>");
        });
    }
 }

        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message,null, null);
        }
    }
```

Ive seen the View used in others sms codes, but what do i have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the button variable first:

```
Button sendMySmsBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Also, you need to fix the capitalization of the setOnClickListener method:

```
sendMySmsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
```

Make sure you've added the SEND_SMS permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Your code from `Button sendMySmsBtn...` to `...here>");
    });` needs to be wrapped in an `onCreate` method like this:

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button sendMySmsBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

sendMySmsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
sendMySmsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick()
    {
        sendSMS("<the number goes here>", "<message goes here>");
    });

   }
```

Make sure you've got a layout-file called `activity_main.xml` that contains a button called button1

Import `android.view.View.OnClickListener` and correct the capitalization of `onClick`

Comment: I have the manifest in shape yes, still no luck though i added you line and put in the capitals

Comment: Added your oncreate, still i need to do something with the OnClickListener. I updated my original post

Comment: You're getting there :-)! Use the suggested option to import `OnClickListener` on View and correct the capitalization of `onClick`

Comment: I did that, managed to get it to actually open up on my phone without errors (2 images were missing though but nota big deal, the button was there), but when i click the button the app crashes.

    Sending SMS message: uid 10158 does not have 
    android.permission.SEND_SMS.

And my manifest is in shape, but my phone is android 7 and i read about the permission changes (ask "on demand" for permissions") in android M and that makes me think i need to add more code to ask form permission to use SMS_SEND?

Comment: Congrats on getting the app to run :)! Yes, you're right, the permission model changed with Android 6.0. To run your app for testing purposes, go into your phone's system settings, select "Apps", find your app in this list, tap on it, then tap on "Permissions". In this list, switch on the "SMS" permission. Then try to send the SMS in the app again. Once it works, check out this blog post to see a sample of how to request permissions: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: It works, put the number to my own number and when i press send i get an sms with my message, YAY! :D

So now whats left is the permission asking "on demand"